# Registered Voice Control Definition file doesn't seem to work

Tags: c#, windows-10-universal, cortana

I am registering the following VCD.xml file in my c# Windows 10 Universal application, but I can't get Cortana to respond to them, it just Bing searches every time.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<VoiceCommands xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/voicecommands/1.2">
  <CommandSet xml:lang="en-us" Name="UniversalAppCommandSet_en-us">
    <AppName> Spang </AppName>
    <Example> Tell me the time </Example>
    <Command Name="TellTime">
      <Example> tell me the time </Example>
      <ListenFor RequireAppName="BeforeOrAfterPhrase"> tell me the time </ListenFor>
      <Feedback> Getting the time for you. </Feedback>
      <Navigate/>
    </Command>
  </CommandSet>
</VoiceCommands>
```

I'm registering in OnLaunched, as per Microsoft directions.

```
    try
    {
        // Install the main VCD. 
        StorageFile pSFeVCD = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/VCD.xml"));
        await Windows.ApplicationModel.VoiceCommands.VoiceCommandDefinitionManager.InstallCommandDefinitionsFromStorageFileAsync(pSFeVCD);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Successfully installed voice commands.");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Installing Voice Commands Failed: " + ex.ToString());
    }
```

I've trying speaking and typing the command but with no luck.  It instantly performs a Bing search without a pause.

Nick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured it out, my language was incorrect, as I have English (United Kingdom) on this PC, the language should be "en-gb" not "en-us".